# how can we know if an email sent from salesforce is actually sent?

Tags: soql, workflow

i have an workflow setup to send an email alert.
For some reason some emails are not received by the contacts. Is there a way we could identify if the emails were sent or not successfully.

I have a Vf page which provides a search result and has a checkbox to select and an option to send emails to those contacts in the search result. When the checkbox is checked and send email button is clicked an field gets updated which triggers a workflow to fire and send an email alert. These search results are from a custom object and would like some way to identify that the email was sent successfully.

I know we cant get the status of emails immediately, something like a batch job which runs once everyday to check the emails are sent or not and updates a custom object which is from where the workflow is fired.

Can this be tracked or queried from ?

Comment: Does the workflow use an HTML email template?

Comment: yes it does.. i am using an email template.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is an Email log that you could use. It's available in the setup menu under Monitoring.

It's only for the past 30 days and you would have to manually check it.

From the email log page: "Email logs describe all emails sent through salesforce.com and can be used to help identify the status of an email delivery. Email logs are CSV files that provide information such as the email address of each email sender and its recipient, the date and time each email was sent, and any error code associated with each email. Logs are only available for the past 30 days."

Answer (score 3):

To add to Salesforce's suggestion you could also look at using Compliance BCC'ing to get a copy of emails sent:  http://ap1.salesforce.com/help/doc/en/admin_compliancebcc.htm